# How will I get the look up id?

Tags: ios, ios4

I want to implement the check update feature in my app. I have explored some of the blogs and tutorials.based on those links , We can implement through lookup and searchAPI. So I need to put it in itunes store after that only i will get lookup id. My confusion ,, How will i check it before put in itunes is it work or not ? please provide some guidelines...

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is the Apple ID. That's generated when you add the app to iTunes Connect, and is displayed there. So you (i) create an entry for your app; then (ii) take the ID, put it into your app and submit your binary.